# Installation failure of 18.04

Tags: system-installation, usb, 18.04, live-usb, laptop

I made a bootable USB, following https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 . I then went to the BOOT MENU on my ACER laptop and changed the boot menu to boot from my USB with Ubuntu.

I followed the ubuntu downloading instructions. At the end it asked me to restart the computer.

I restarted the computer and pulled out my USB. When I pulled it out, a symbol displayed on the screen saying 'NO BOOTABLE DEVICE'.

Comment: That sounds frustrating! Can you edit your question to clarify what disk image you used and what you remember about the steps you took? Right now there's just not enough information for us to help you.

Comment: Yes of course. I will edit it

Comment: @K7AAY I do apologize for the lack of information and if it was confusing. I am in a rush to solve it because I need my computer for work.

Comment: @Amanda I have edited the information. I hope this is enough.

Comment: Do you know how to get back to the boot menu? If your Acer started to boot from USB and then you yanked it, it may just need to be restart, or you may need to confirm that the built in disk is still one of the boot options.

Comment: Do you want to dual boot or install Ubuntu only wiping out windows? Which option did you choose during installation process?

Comment: @PranalNarayan I chose to wipe out windows and just choose Ubuntu. My coworkers instructed me to do so.

Comment: @Amanda Yes I know how to get to the boot menu. the USB boot option is listed at the top of the boot options so when i take it out from restart or even just turning on the laptop without the USB it displays NO BOOTABLE DEVICE.

Comment: " I followed the ubuntu downloading instructions. At the end it asked me to restart the computer. " Did you mean to say you installed Ubuntu Desktop, which looks like the process outlined at https://www.ostechnix.com/installing-ubuntu-18-04-lts-desktop-and-server/

Comment: @K7AAY yes the desktop. on the USB and i'm trying to get it on my computer and be able to use it without the USB.

Comment: I understand you wish to boot Ubuntu from the internal hard drive. What you are not telling us is how you installed it.

Comment: Based on what you've said it's fairly obvious that your Ubuntu install process failed, that there is a problem with the target drive you installed Ubuntu on or that the drive is not being recognized in the BIOS boot sequence.

Probably the most painless way to proceed is to do another clean install, paying close attention to each step you take and writing down the selections you made when the install asks you questions.  And of course noting any error messages.

Comment: If you leave the USB plugged in does grub startup OK?, One of the grub menu items should be the internal drive. Try that. If that works OK you just need to re-install grub.